# NestWhile with input as a list

Tags: functions

I'm wondering how I can use `NestWhile` if my input is a list:

```
NestWhile[function,{1,2,3,4},...]
```

For example, I want `NestWhile` to stop until the second element of my output list larger than 3. How to realize it?

Comment: What function did you want to apply to your list?

Comment: Look at [`Fold`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fold.html) or [`FoldList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FoldList.html).

Comment: Sorry my problem. The second element of the list will be added 1 every time I run the function.

Comment: Assuming your `function` takes and returns  a  list of length 4 ( for example, `f[{x_,y_,z_,w_}]:= {x y, y+1, 2z, (x+ w + y) ^2}`), try `NestWhile[function,{1,2,3,4}, #[[2]]<=3&]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is somewhat unclear what you want to achieve, so this may not be it, but I think you might be interested in a combination of `Map` and `TakeWhile`. See for instance this simple example:

```
list = Range[0, 10];
f /@ TakeWhile[list, # < 3 &]

(* Out: {f[0], f[1], f[2]} *)
```